# How to save data from several combobox in a list, python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tkinter, combobox

I have a problem with this part of my code, I am making a system that saves data on domestic gas cylinders, first it asks how many cylinders are going to be stored and then proceeds to select the characteristics of the cylinders with combobox, and here This is where the error is, the data is not shown by the console, this is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Toplevel, getint, ttk

ventana = Tk()

def ejecucion():
    can = cantidad.get() +1
    ventana2 = Toplevel()

def guardar():
    print(lista) #SE GUARDARAN LOS DATOS DE LAS LISTAS EN LA BASE DE DATOS 

def imprimir():
    empresa.get()
    tamano.get()
    pico.get()
    

for cilindros in range(1, can ,1):

    titulo = LabelFrame(ventana2, text= f"Cilindro {cilindros}")
    titulo.pack()



    empresa = ttk.Combobox(titulo, values=["Radelco", "PacoGas", "Comunal"])
    empresa.bind("<<ComboboxSelect>>", imprimir)
    empresa.pack()

    tamano = ttk.Combobox(titulo, values=["Pequena", "Mediana", "Regular", "Grande"])
    tamano.bind("<<ComboboxSelect>>", imprimir)
    tamano.pack()

    pico = ttk.Combobox(titulo, values=["Pequeno", "Mediano", "Grande"])
    pico.bind("<<ComboboxSelect>>", imprimir)
    pico.pack()

    lista.append(imprimir)

Button(ventana2, text="Guardar", command=guardar).pack()


lista = []
cantidad = IntVar()

Label(ventana, text="cantidad cilindros").pack()
Entry(ventana, textvariable=cantidad).pack()
Button(ventana, text="listo", command=ejecucion).pack()

ventana.mainloop()
```

In the end, these obtained data will be stored in a database, Thanks in advance.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: I don't see any `open()`, `write()` , `close()`. Where do you try to write data?

Comment: BTW: if you want to display data in console then you should use `print()` - i.e. `print( empresa.get() )`, etc.

Comment: This code doesn't run because of this error: `NameError: name 'can' is not defined` and some other reasons.

Comment: this code can't even run. You create local variable `can` inside `ejecucion()` but you also try to use this variable outside `ejecucion()` and this raise error. Porbably you put code with wrong indentations - so code is useless.

Comment: if you create widgets in `for`-loop then you should keep them on list to have access to all of them. But you assign always to the same `empresa`, `tamano`, `pico` - so you have access only to last created widgets. You append `imprimir` to `listo` - and this is useless. You should append list `[empresa, tamano, pico]`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to save all the data of each one of the cylinders that I want to place, to show them in the console, example: Cylinder 1|Empresa: Radelco, Tamano: Grande, Pico: Mediano

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't even work because you put it with wrong indentations. Next time put correct code.

---

You keep `imprimir` on `listo` but you should keep list `[empresa, tamano, pico]`
(or even `[cilindros ,empresa, tamano, pico]`)

You don't need function `imprimir()` because all you have do in `guardar()` when you click button.

It should use `for`-loop to run with every list `[cilindros ,empresa, tamano, pico]` in `listo`, and use `.get()` to get values from `Comboboxes` on this list.

And later you can write it as text file with `open()`, `write()`, `close()` but I used module `csv` to write it as `CSV` which you can open in `Excel` (or Python module `pandas`) to make other calculations.

---

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

# --- functions ---   # PEP8: all functions before main code

def ejecucion():
    can = cantidad.get() +1
    ventana2 = tk.Toplevel()

    def guardar():

        data = []

        # SE GUARDARAN LOS DATOS DE LAS LISTAS EN LA BASE DE DATOS 
        for cilindros, empresa, tamano, pico in lista:
            print('cilindros:', cilindros)
            print('empresa:', empresa.get())
            print('tamano :', tamano.get())
            print('pico   :', pico.get())
            print('---------------------------')
            data.append([cilindros, empresa.get(), tamano.get(), pico.get()])
            
        # ---
        
        with open('output.csv', 'w') as fh:
            cvs_writer = csv.writer(fh)
            # write header (single row)
            cvs_writer.writerow(["cilindros", "empresa", "tamano", "pico"])  # writerow (without char `s` at the end) to write one list (with single row).
            # write data   (many rows)
            cvs_writer.writerows(data)                                       # writerows (with char `s` at the end) to write list of lists (with many rows). 

    for cilindros in range(1, can):

        titulo = tk.LabelFrame(ventana2, text= f"Cilindro {cilindros}")
        titulo.pack()

        empresa = ttk.Combobox(titulo, values=["Radelco", "PacoGas", "Comunal"])
        empresa.pack()

        tamano = ttk.Combobox(titulo, values=["Pequena", "Mediana", "Regular", "Grande"])
        tamano.pack()

        pico = ttk.Combobox(titulo, values=["Pequeno", "Mediano", "Grande"])
        pico.pack()

        lista.append([cilindros, empresa, tamano, pico])

    tk.Button(ventana2, text="Guardar", command=guardar).pack()

# --- main ---

lista = []

ventana = tk.Tk()

cantidad = tk.IntVar(ventana)

tk.Label(ventana, text="cantidad cilindros").pack()
tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=cantidad).pack()
tk.Button(ventana, text="listo", command=ejecucion).pack()

ventana.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)